# How can I iterate over test_function in pytest for multiple values?

Tags: python, linux, integration-testing, pytest, python-unittest

I want to know how can I iterate over a test_funtion() in pytest for different values?
Eg.

```
list = ['ls','ps', 'df' ,'du'] #list of Linux commands
def test_method(self):
    for I in list:
       r=subprocess.check_output(I)
       if r:
          assert True
       else: 
          assert False
```

Now when I run pytest -k test_method,
It shows me only one test case passed.
But I want all 4 cases ran using single function and need 4 test cases passed in output.
How can I achieve it?

Comment: Do not iterate over the function, iterate over this values inside the function. What i mean to say is, run your function over all the values of the list inside the test function, not an ideal thing to do though

Comment: Okay by doing so I am getting only one testcase overall passed but I have multiple values. So is there anyway to get output like 4 testcases passed in this case?

Comment: You can but that is not how you should do unit testing. Your unit tests should be exclusive of each other. If all the values of your tests mean somethiing else, you should write separate tests for each.

Comment: Right but the test method is common in all 4 test cases so I don't want to make it redundant, unlike it should use single function to multiple commands. Writing multiple functions for same test method is not a good idea.

Comment: Then why are you testing it for 4 different inputs? If it is common and the test is passing for one input, then there is no need to test the same for different input

Comment: Correct but each command has different meaning. I have shown you few examples, so for n no of testcase (commands) I need to test all commands seperately as testcases. That is what I am trying to achieve here.

Comment: If they are different commands, you should definitely cover them in separate test methods. You mustn't test them in a single test method

Comment: Check out [Parametrizing fixtures and test functions](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/parametrize.html).

Comment: @Ezio test parametrization is a standard pattern in software testing. Writing separate tests for multiple elements of function's input space is not recommended as it will result in a lot of redundant code, increasing the maintenance burden. Also, "there is no need to test the same for different input" - that's simply not true.

Comment: Okay but parameterizing fixtures won't help to class function right? I have class and function defined inside class and the command values i am getting from yaml file. How can I make a change?

Comment: First of all, what class functions are you talking about? If you ask about parametrizing test class _methods_, `pytest.mark.parametrize` handles that well. Your test classes are not allowed to subclass `unittest.TestCase` though, as pytest features are not compatible with `unittest`. _I have ...  the command values i am getting from yaml file_ - please do not ask multiple questions at once, this is not a help forum. Finish with the current question, then open a new one for the other problem.

Comment: Okay I meant that I have , class Test(unittest.TestCase) in which this function I need to use.

Answer (score 6):

expanding on previous answer by @Nithin-Mohan

```
commands = ['ls','ps', 'df' ,'du'] #list of Linux commands
@pytest.mark.parametrize("cmds",commands)
def test_method(cmds):
   r=subprocess.check_output(cmds)
   if r:
      assert True
   else:
      assert False
```

Here is the output running as 4 separate tests

```
 test_sflow.py::test_method[ls] PASSED [ 25%]                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 test_sflow.py::test_method[ps] PASSED [ 50%]                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 test_sflow.py::test_method[df] PASSED [ 75%]                                                                                                                                                                                                       
 test_sflow.py::test_method[du] PASSED [ 100%]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [pytest parameterization](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/example/parametrize.html#different-options-for-test-ids)

It has got a variety of types. Pass values as tuples and pass to the test functions as arguments

Comment: Okay so what if my function is class function? How can I use parameterization in class function?

Comment: @DhavalMehta then decorate the method, not the class.

Comment: Okay can I get some clue? I am not aware the method. TIA.